# How to properly label someone as "Spanish Speaking"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

I'm updating a  list of employees for a client and came across one labeled as "Spanish Speaking." I'd like to replace that with the appropriate word or words in Spanish.

The three options I've found are:

- Habla Español
- Hispanohablante
- Hispanoparlante

But I'm not sure which one is correct, or if it even matters using English is fine. I'm trying to be both politically and linguistically correct.

I don't know if it matters in this context, but this client is likely to only be dealing with native Spanish speakers either from Mexico or the US.

Comment: *Hispanohablante* is more common in Spain. I think *hispanoparlante* is preferred in Mexico but I'm not sure. Besides that, all three forms are grammatically correct but only the two last options are nouns/adjectives, while the first is a clause. Also, remember demonyms are never capitalized in Spanish.

Comment: @Yay Why are they never capitalized? I'm both curious, and I might need an argument for the client. I'm going to use the word as a continuation of the employee's title or a stand-alone line beneath. Would it still not be capitalized?

Comment: Nope. I cannot tell you why, it's just the rules. Adjectives aren't capitalized except when they are a part of a name (Puerto *Rico*, Estrella *Polar*, Biblioteca *Nacional*, Edad *Media*), or, occasionally, in certain titles (Isabel la *Católica*, Atila el *Huno*, el Cid *Campeador*), but not when they are a mere demonym. For an authoritative reference, see this entry on [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=may%C3%BAscula) (only in Spanish).

Comment: Hispanohablante is preferred here in Mexico.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All work, but you need a *de* in front of *habla española* (note the gender) because that's a noun phrase rather than an adjective.  You'll also hear the variants *de habla hispana* and *de habla castellana*, in addition to extra adjectival option *hispanófono*.

Based on Google's [N-Grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=hispanohablante%2Chispanoparlante%2Cde+habla+hispana%2Cde+habla+espa%C3%B1ola%2Cde+habla+castellana&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chispanohablante%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chispanoparlante%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cde%20habla%20hispana%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cde%20habla%20espa%C3%B1ola%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cde%20habla%20castellana%3B%2Cc0), we can see that *de habla [hispana/española/castellana]* has historically been the most common structure, although *hispanohablante* is definitely rising in popularity.  N-Grams doesn't distinguish by country, but I don't really ever hear *hispanoparlante* these days from anyone, and hear *hispanohablante* and the *de habla X* regularly enough that none strikes me as odd.

You can also do the same with most other languages:

- **Portuguese**: *lusohablante*, *lusoparlante*, *lusófono*, or *de habla portuguesa*
- **French**: *francohablante*, *francoparlante*, *francófono*, *de habla francesa*
- **Chinese**: *sinohablante*, *sinoparlante*, *sinófono*, *de habla china*
- **German**: *germanohablante*, *germanoparlante*, *germanófono*, *de habla alemana*
- **Italian**: *italohablante*, *italoparlante*, *italófono*, *de habla italiana*
- **English**: *anglohablante*, *angloparlante*, *anglófono*, *de habla inglesa*

Note that the adjectival forms will use a compositional element based on the Latin form of the language's name, rather than an adjective, and so is often a teeny bit different (and other times very different) from the language's normal adjectival form.